# Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

App crashes in the emulator while it works fine on my phone. As far I remember, I didn't make any change and its suddenly started occurring.  I have tried to find the solution but no luck. I would appreciate if you could help me on this

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.stampedesolution.fv">



<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/roadie"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/roadie"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".QrCodeScannerActivity2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".QrCodeScannerActivity1"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ProfileActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AbortMissionActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AddNewRecording"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AddNewPhotoActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AddNewRemarkActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AddNewPhoneNumberActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AddNewAddressActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ShowInfoActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MenuActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
    -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="Maps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.stampedesolution.fv.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
    <service android:name=".Firebase.FirebaseMessagingReciever">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.stampedesolution.fv"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {

    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs =
                [
                        'src/main/res/layout',
                        'src/main/res'
                ]
    }
}
}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.evrencoskun.library:tableview:0.8.8'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.0.2'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0'
implementation  "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.1"
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9.13'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation 'com.github.mkhoiron:Actionsheet-android:0.1'
implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.evrencoskun.library:tableview:0.8.8'

implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:jackson-android-networking:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'



implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

}

### Error

```
Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.stampedesolution.fv-wiGk1bQhfb01ooy7YPDN1w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.stampedesolution.fv-wiGk1bQhfb01ooy7YPDN1w==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.stampedesolution.fv-wiGk1bQhfb01ooy7YPDN1w==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:256)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:855)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:950)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1188)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2462)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2454)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6343)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.stampedesolution.fv-wiGk1bQhfb01ooy7YPDN1w==/base.apk because: Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.stampedesolution.fv-wiGk1bQhfb01ooy7YPDN1w==/base.apk': Bad encoded_value method type size 7
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:365)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:107)
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:444)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:403)
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:101)
    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
    at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
    at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:851)
            ... 13 more
2019-12-01 14:51:22.897 9509-9509/com.stampedesolution.fv E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.stampedesolution.fv, PID: 9509
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.stampedesolution.fv-wiGk1bQhfb01ooy7YPDN1w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.stampedesolution.fv-wiGk1bQhfb01ooy7YPDN1w==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.stampedesolution.fv-wiGk1bQhfb01ooy7YPDN1w==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6988)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.stampedesolution.fv-wiGk1bQhfb01ooy7YPDN1w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.stampedesolution.fv-wiGk1bQhfb01ooy7YPDN1w==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.stampedesolution.fv-wiGk1bQhfb01ooy7YPDN1w==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(AppComponentFactory.java:147)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6972)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Failed to open dex files from /data/app/com.stampedesolution.fv-wiGk1bQhfb01ooy7YPDN1w==/base.apk because: Bad encoded_array value: Failure to verify dex file '/data/app/com.stampedesolution.fv-wiGk1bQhfb01ooy7YPDN1w==/base.apk': Bad encoded_value method type size 7
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:365)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:107)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:444)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:403)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:126)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:74)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:87)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:116)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:114)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoaderWithSharedLibraries(ApplicationLoaders.java:60)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:851)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:950)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1188)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2462)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2454)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6343)
                ... 8 more
2019-12-01 14:51:23.061 2130-2159/? E/system_server: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2019-12-01 14:51:23.240 1794-1947/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-12-01 14:51:23.240 1794-1947/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-12-01 14:51:23.320 1775-2611/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2019-12-01 14:51:23.320 1775-2611/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2019-12-01 14:51:23.625 2130-2130/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/GoogleSdkSetup/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:256)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:370)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5951)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1941)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:541)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:349)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:908)
2019-12-01 14:51:23.627 2130-2130/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/priv-app/GoogleSdkSetup/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:256)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:370)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5951)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1941)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:541)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:349)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
```